# Is there any way to do Bi-directional Infinite scrolling in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, react-infinite-scroll-component, react-virtuoso

I am using react-infite-scroll-component and react-virtuoso for inverse infinite scrolling in real-time chat app.
And the problem is when when chat has more than 100 unread messages, then it's more difficult to display all unread messages at a time.
I would like to paginate it on bottom as well without Intersection Observer..

Is there any way to do it with react-infite-scroll-component and **react-virtuoso**?

prepending item works fine but i want to add items down side as well when user move downwards.